# Block specific keyword search from form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

my search form on my page is

```
<form id="headbar-search" action="search.php" method="GET" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech">
<input type="text" name="search" id="jsid-search-input" value="<?php echo$_GET['search']; ?>" class="ui-autocomplete-input search search_input" placeholder="Search&#8230;" tabindex="1"/>
<div class="ui-widget"></div>            
</form>
```

i dont want users to be able to search certain words....

if they search "f***" i want it to redirect to the home page or a simple javascript notification that says not allowed.... thanks!

Comment: you could keep an array of invalid words and check against it

Comment: @Nouphal.M how would i do that?

Comment: explode the search term and check with in_array

Answer (score 0):

Either trap for bad words in your php script, or put your php request behind some javascript and trap there. example....

html...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
        <script src="functions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="headbar-search">
            <input type="text" id="search-box"/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="search();"></input>      
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

js...

```
var badWords = ["gosh","darn"];
function search() {
    var searchStr = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
    var badWordHit = false;
    for (key in badWords) {
        if (badWords[key] == searchStr) {
            badWordHit = true;
        }
    }
    if (badWordHit) {
        alert("Oh no you didn't!");
    }   else    {
        // ajax request here
    }       
}
```

Comment: If you need help with your ajax request, go with jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: have you tested this? this is pretty much what i was looking for @LordOfTongs

Comment: I changed a few of your ID's around, but yes this is tested and works.

Comment: ok im going to test it and if it works ill mark it as correct answer